# Video embedding in Html

Tags: html, embed

I tried using the embed tags to embed a video from YouTube to my web page , it worked properly in my computer but as i gave it to my friend to view it , the video was not working . 
Please help me guys .

```
<object width="560" height="315">
<param name="movie"   value="http://www.youtube.com/v/yXT012us9ng?hl=en_US&amp;version=3">
</param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess"  value="always">
</param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/yXT012us9ng?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: do ur friend has an internet connection ??

Comment: How do you expect that anyone can tell what's wrong without seeing the HTML?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it doesn't work. You should provide some code.

Comment: I don't know about it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be good , so just try and find out if ur friend has an internet connection or not 'cause ur embedding a file for the net . If he/she doesn't have an internet connect better u get a download of that video .